# error: attempt to call function 'is_colliding' in base 'null instance' on a null instance

Tags: godot

I've just started making a basic fps in the Godot engine, and I'm currently stuck on making a basic Raycast weapon. I've looked up tutorials from Coding With Tom, Gabaj YT, and multiple others, and yet no matter which one, I always end up writing the same piece of code:

if Raycast.is_Colliding:

and no matter how exactly I copy it down, I always end up with the same error:

error: attempt to call function 'is_colliding' in base 'null instance' on a null instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Raycast`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast.html) is a class. And [`is_colliding`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast.html#class-raycast-method-is-colliding) is one of its methods. But it is not an static method, you need an instance of `Raycast`.

Chances are, you do have an instance. If you have been following the tutorials, presumably you have a `Raycast` node in the scene tree added from the editor, and it is called… let me guess… `Raycast`. *Yes, I do it too. Until it begins to be an issue and I rename it to something more meaningful or go for a different approach, but I digress.*

The issue is that you are not referring the `Raycast` instance. You can reference nodes from your script using [`$`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/nodes_and_scene_instances.html#syntactic-sugar), like this: `$Raycast`. It is a shorthand for using the [`get_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node) method. See [Nodes and scene instances](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/nodes_and_scene_instances.html). *To be clear, what you put after `$` is the relative path on the scene tree, so it might not be just the name of the node. Here I'm assuming the node is a direct child of the node that has the script you are writing.*

Thus, I would expect code like this:

```
if $Raycast.is_colliding():
```

---

Granted, you will see code that does look like this:

```
if raycast.is_colliding():
```

That is because somewhere in the script they have a line that looks something like this:

```
onready var raycast := $Raycast
```

Which declares a variable `raycast` and - [on ready](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#onready-keyword) - sets it to a reference to the node, and then they can continue using that variable form there. *With video tutorials some might skim over that. Here I found it on a Garbaj video on the topic: [Godot FPS Hitscan Weapons Tutorial at 1:52](https://youtu.be/4jbfIN4t83k?t=112)*